# getting exponential moving average over complete data length in julia

Tags: pandas, julia

I want to use the ewma (Exponential Weighted Moving Average) function available in the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html) library in Python with an equivalent Julia function. In Julia, there is a function called `MarketTechnicals.ema(m)` which calculates the EMA values. However, this function starts calculating values from the `m`th element in a data series of size `n`, so the resulting data would be of length `(n-m+1)`. While this is understandable since the span is `m`, the pandas ewma function calculates this from the very first element, no matter what the span length is, as shown below:

```py
#python
import pandas as pd
data = {"val": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['val'].ewm(m).mean()     
#output m=3
0    1.000000
1    1.571429
2    2.189189
3    2.851429
4    3.555698
5    4.299079
```

This Python code returns n values if the length of df['val'] is n. But following Julia snippet would be of length (n-m+1)

```
# julia
using DataFrames, MarketTechnicals
df = DataFrame(val = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ema(df.val,m)              
#output m=3
4×1 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.0
 3.0
 4.0
 5.0
```

I came across a [repo](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl/blob/main/src/Pandas.jl) that allows using pandas functionality in Julia, but I am not clear with the syntax and couldn't find any examples online.

Can someone help me with a Julia equivalent for the pandas ewma function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pd.ewma explanation from the pandas source code, I created following function for julia. It caters options of `span, com, halflife, adjust, ignore` parameters

```
# julia code to recreate pandas.ewma
abstract type AlphaCalc end

struct Com{T<:Float64}<:AlphaCalc
  com::T
end

struct Span{T<:Float64}<:AlphaCalc
  span::T
end

struct Halflife{T<:Float64}<:AlphaCalc
  halflife::T
end

calcAlpha(val::Com)      = 1/(1 + val.com)
calcAlpha(val::Span)     = 2/(1 + val.span)
calcAlpha(val::Halflife) = 1 - exp(log(0.5)/val.halflife)

# julia code to recreate pandas.ewma
function ewma(
  data::AbstractVector,
  alphaMethod::AlphaCalc;
  adjust::Bool=true,
  ignore_na::Bool=false
)

  alpha = calcAlpha(alphaMethod)
  n_samples = length(data)
  ewma_result = Vector{Float64}(undef, n_samples)

  if ignore_na
    ewma_result[1] = first(data)
    weights = [1.]

    for i in 2:n_samples
      if isnan(data[i])
        ewma_result[i] = ewma_result[i-1]
      else
        if !isnan(data[i-1])
          weights .*= (1 - alpha)
          push!(weights, 1)
        end
        # When adjust is True, use the weighted sum divided by the sum of weights
        if adjust
          weighted_sum = sum([weight * value for (weight, value) in zip(weights, data[1:i][.!isnan.(data[1:i])])])
          ewma_result[i] = weighted_sum / sum(weights)
        # When adjust is False, use the recursive formula
        else
          ewma_result[i] = (1 - alpha) * ewma_result[i-1] + alpha * data[i]
        end
      end
    end
  else
    ewma_result[1] = first(data)
    for i in 2:n_samples
      # When adjust is True, use the weighted sum divided by the sum of weights
      if adjust
        weights = [(1 - alpha) ^ (i - j - 1) for j in 0:(i-1)]
        weighted_sum = sum([weight * value for (weight, value) in zip(weights, data[1:i])])
        ewma_result[i] = weighted_sum / sum(weights)
      # When adjust is False, use the recursive formula
      else
        ewma_result[i] = (1 - alpha) * ewma_result[i-1] + alpha * data[i]
      end
    end
  end
  return ewma_result
end
```

It was tested in julia as-

```
data = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 8.0]
ewma_result = ewma(data, Com(5.), adjust=false, ignore_na=false);
println("EWMA result: ", ewma_result)
ewma_result = ewma(data, Span(5.), adjust=false, ignore_na=true);
println("EWMA result: ", ewma_result)
ewma_result = ewma(data, Halflife(5.), adjust=true, ignore_na=true);
println("EWMA result: ", ewma_result)

#outputs 
EWMA result: [1.0, 1.1666666666666667, 1.4722222222222223, 1.8935185185185186, 2.4112654320987654, 3.0093878600823047, 3.841156550068587]
EWMA result: [1.0, 1.3333333333333335, 1.888888888888889, 2.5925925925925926, 3.3950617283950617, 4.263374485596708, 5.508916323731139]
EWMA result: [1.0, 1.5346019613807635, 2.0921248294619423, 2.672350105842331, 3.2749760411274242, 3.8996216516650244, 4.754261118819774]
```

with corresponding python functionality as-

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 8.0]
>>> data = pd.Series(data)
>>> data.ewm(com=5.0, adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean()
0    1.000000
1    1.166667
2    1.472222
3    1.893519
4    2.411265
5    3.009388
6    3.841157
dtype: float64
>>> data.ewm(span=5.0, adjust=False, ignore_na=True).mean()
0    1.000000
1    1.333333
2    1.888889
3    2.592593
4    3.395062
5    4.263374
6    5.508916
dtype: float64
>>> data.ewm(halflife=5.0, adjust=True, ignore_na=True).mean()
0    1.000000
1    1.534602
2    2.092125
3    2.672350
4    3.274976
5    3.899622
6    4.754261
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Following Dan's comment, the following code gives the expected result:

   ```
   julia> ewma(w; m=3,a=m/(m+1)) = map!(
              i->i==1 ? w[1] :
              ((1-a)*w[i]+a*(1-a^(i-1))*r[i-1])/(1-a^i), (r = similar(w);),
              eachindex(w)
          )
   ewma (generic function with 1 method)

   julia> ewma(1.0:6.0; m=3)
   6-element Vector{Float64}:
    1.0
    1.5714285714285714
    2.189189189189189
    2.8514285714285714
    3.5556978233034573
    4.299079299079299
   ```
2. Note: The following code is inspired by the proposed approach in [this blog](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/ewma/). In the following function, `a` is the smoothing coefficient:

   ```
   julia> function ewma(obs::Vector, a::Float64)
              T = length(obs)
              EWMA = Vector{Float64}(obs)
              for t∈2:T
                  EWMA[t] = a*obs[t]+(1-a)*EWMA[t-1]
              end
              EWMA
          end
   ewma (generic function with 1 method)

   julia> ewma([40, 45, 43, 31, 20], 0.3)
   5-element Vector{Float64}:
    40.0
    41.5
    41.949999999999996
    38.66499999999999
    33.06549999999999
   ```

Comment: Won't this modify the input vector? Is that intentional, and if so, the function should be called `ewma!`

Comment: @DNF, No, it won't, so there's no need for the exclamation mark.

Comment: I checked, and it does _indeed_ modify the input vector, if the input vector is a `Vector{Float64}`, otherwise it creates a copy. So the function will have dramatically and dangerously different behaviour depending on the input type. I suggest writing `EWMA = similar(obs, Float64)` instead. It is also better style. `EWMA = Vector{Float64}(obs)` is also better, the assertion style is not very nice, imho.

Comment: @DNF, That behavior is not supposed to be dependent on Float64. It's strange. Why should it be different than `Int64`? Yeah, I thought of `similar(...)`, but it needed a line like `EWMA[1]=obs[1]`, so I decided not to use `similar`. But, in this case, it's better to use `similar` since the `EWMA::Vector{Float64} = obs` doesn't do the job in some cases. I'll edit it.

Comment: @DNF, Thank you. the comment was great. Can you suggest a better replacement for `axes(obs, 1)[2:end]`? Since it performs a copy, I wonder if we can do it efficiently rather than the existing structure.

Comment: Since your arrays are of type `Vector` you can just write `for t in 2:length(obs)`. If you want to allow more generic inputs, maybe `for t in eachindex(obs)[begin+1:end]` or use `firstindex`/`lastindex`?

Comment: After `using OffsetArrays, ImageFiltering`, the following definition will do: `EWM(v; m=3) = imfilter(v, OffsetArray(reverse((1-1/(m+1)).^(0:length(v))), -length(v):0), NA())` (@Shayan you can add this to answer)

Comment: Finally, another version which has some tricky stuff going on: `ewma(w; m=3,a=m/(m+1)) = map!(i->i==1 ? w[1] : ((1-a)*w[i]+a*(1-a^(i-1))*r[i-1])/(1-a^i), (r = similar(w);),eachindex(w))` . Trying this with `ewma(1.0:6.0; m=3)` gives the OP result.

Comment: @DNF, Sorry for the late response. Thank you for the proposals. I have two questions: 1. Is `2:length()` efficient? 2. Does `eachindex(obs)[begin+1:end]` perform a copy? I think we do have a copy operation due to `:` in slicing.

Comment: @DanGetz, Thank you so much!! I prepended your former hint to the answer. Although it lacks readability, it's great. Sorry for the late response; I wasn't online for a while.

Comment: @Shayan `2:length()` is efficient, you must just ensure that it is correct. Indexing into a range with another range simply produces a new range, so `eachindex(obs)[begin+1:end]` does not allocate any memory.

Comment: @DNF, You're right. According to the official doc: *"The common idiom of using 1:n to index into an AbstractArray is not safe **if the Array uses unconventional indexing**, and may cause a segmentation fault if bounds checking is turned off."* Thank you so much.